# How to update database with entire html table (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this for several days now. I have searched on how to update tables and have managed to get as far as to update rows, but only the last one in the table. So now i am trying to get a loop that loops through all the inputs and updates the database with the inputted values. I think the code that needs to be corrected is located near the end of the code

What i want to do:

- Get/display database in html table
- Change values of certain columns
- Update the database table using a submit button which updates every row in database

Here is a picture of what the table looks like in web view:

[image: Table as it would look in web view]

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include '../db/connect.php';
?>
   <form action='test7.php' method="post">
      <table border='1'>
         <?php
            $result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users");
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td colspan='3'>CLASS 1</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               //All table rows in database presented in html table
               while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='user_id[]' value='".$row['user_id']."' /></td>";
                  echo "<td>username  :<input type='text' name='username[]' value='".$row['username']."' /></td>";
                  echo "<td>email  :<input type='text' name='email[]' value='".$row['email']."' /></td>";
                  echo "<td>rank  :<input type='number' name='rank[]' value='".$row['rank']."' /></td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
               }
            echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE' />";
         ?>
      <table>
   </form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 
      $total = count($_POST['rank']); 
      $user_id_arr = $_POST['user_id']; 
      $rank_arr = $_POST['rank']; 
      for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){ 
         $user_id = $user_id_arr[$i]; 
         $rank = $rank_arr[$i]; 
         $query = "UPDATE users SET `rank`= '".$rank."' WHERE `user_id`= '".$user_id."'"; 
         $MySQLi_CON->query($query); 
         header('Location: test7.php');
      } 
   }
?>
```

When I press the UPDATE button, i get `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in...`.

It refers to line 30 which is this line:

`$query = "UPDATE user SET rank=$_POST[rank][$row] WHERE user_id=$value ";`

EDIT: Edited the code above to the working code. Thank you @Frayne Konok for your help.

Comment: So.. var_dump($_POST[rank][$row]) and var_dump($value)

Comment: your update query may be doing wrong, try with quota.

Comment: you make a mistake here, you use the same resource to the foreach loop, so you face some unknown problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You did a great mistake here, Why you use the `$result` in foreach
>   loop?? FRom where the `$result` comes?? The `$result` is the resource
>   of the `sql` query.

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $total = count($_POST['rank']);
    $user_id_arr = $_POST['user_id'];
    $rank_arr = $_POST['rank'];
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
        $user_id = $user_id_arr[$i];
        $rank = $rank_arr[$i];
        $query = "UPDATE users SET `rank`= '".$rank."' WHERE `user_id`= '".$user_id."'";  
        $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
    }
}
```

Try with this and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't give any errors. However, when I press the update button, none of the fields are being updated in the database. When I press the button, all the values just return to what they were before I changed them.

Comment: if you can make a `sqlfiddle` then i can try or find out the real problem.

Comment: I have never used `sqlfiddle` before but I am trying now. I will write another comment if I manage to make one.

Comment: Okay I think I've made an `sqlfiddle`. The link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d1cd/2/0. Hope you can help me find this problem

Comment: Thank you so much, I am staying tuned.

Comment: @Onret, I check it out and its work. Just change the table name in the update query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The code works now perfectly

Comment: for better HTMl and PHP [download](http://demo.somogro-desh.net/test4.php), Change the database connection.

Answer (score 3):

You are very close.

The issue is that in this code `$_POST[rank][$row]` - rank is an undefined constant.  You need it to be a string, like so `$_POST['rank'][$row]`.  Also, pull the `$POST` variable out of the query directly to allow typecasting - you should always be very uncomfortable when you see a query that has `$_POST` data directly:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    foreach ($result as $row => $value) { 
        // typecast to a number with decimals below.  If you only need integers, than use (int)
        $rank = (float)$_POST['rank'][$row];
        $query = "UPDATE user SET rank={$rank} WHERE user_id={$value}";
        $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
    }
}
```

However, it would be better to use mysqli prepared statements rather than insert the variables directly - as it stand, the above code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Your code should be modified to look something like so to prevent sql injection attacks:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $stmt = $MySQLi_CON->prepare("UPDATE user SET rank= ? WHERE user_id= ?");
    foreach ($result as $row => $value){      
        $stmt->bind_param('di', $_POST['rank'][$row], $value); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and modified the last chunk of code to:  <br/>

`if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $stmt = $MySQLi_CON->prepare("$query = "UPDATE user SET rank= ? WHERE user_id= ?"); 
    foreach ($result as $row => $value){        
        $stmt->bind_param('di', $_POST['rank'][$row], $value);   
        $stmt->execute();  
    }  
    $stmt->close(); 
}` 
It now returns this error:  
 `Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean`

Comment: @cale_b, did you notice? The user use the same `$result` to the loop which is a resource of query.